# PHP implode A, B, C and X others

Tags: php, arrays, implode

Currently I have some code that retrieve names and lists them like `User1, User2 and User3 likes this`

```
$MoreLikers = $this->DBHandle->mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM thread_reply_likes WHERE post_receiver = '".$Row["id"]."'");
while($FetchLikers = $MoreLikers->fetch_array()) {
    $like_user = $this->DBHandle->mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '".$FetchLikers["user_giver"]."'");
    $LuArray = array();
    while($RowLu = $like_user->fetch_array()) {
        $LuArray[] = $RowLu;
    }

    $LuArrayz[] = "";

    foreach($LuArray as $Rowz) {
        $TheLikersList[] =  $Rowz["username"];

    }

    if($MoreLikers->num_rows < 4) {
        $last  = array_slice($TheLikersList, -1);
        $first = join(', ', array_slice($TheLikersList, 0, -1));
        $both  = array_filter(array_merge(array($first), $last), 'strlen');
        $TheLikers = join(' and ', $both);

        $ListLikers = "<i class='fa fa-thumbs-up'></i> " . $TheLikers . " likes this";
    } else {
        // what to put here if num_rows are more than 3?
    }
}
```

What I want to do is, if the numbers of users (num_rows basically) are more than 3, to show it like `User1, User2, User3 and X others likes this` where X is the `num_rows` minus `3`.

I'm not sure how to do that. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `$result->row_count`

Comment: Final edit in my answer (tested and worked).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert `$MoreLikers->num_rows` in the middle :

```
if($MoreLikers->num_rows < 4) {
        $last  = array_slice($TheLikersList, -1);
        $first = join(', ', array_slice($TheLikersList, 0, -1));
        $both  = array_filter(array_merge(array($first), $last), 'strlen');
        $TheLikers = join(' and ', $both);
        $ListLikers = "<i class='fa fa-thumbs-up'></i> " . $TheLikers .
                      " likes this";
} else {
    $three  = array_slice($TheLikersList,0,3);
    $TheLikers = join(', ', $three);
    $ListLikers = "<i class='fa fa-thumbs-up'></i> " . $TheLikers .
                  " and " . ($MoreLikers->num_rows-3) . " others like this"; //<=======
    }
```